# How do I edit each individual array element in v-for loop with Vue3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, momentjs

## Basically I have this calendar row with date info on each element:[image]

I'm trying to stop that loop of single data so that each calendar item has it's own data about the current and the next days.

The first calendar element should always display the current day, the rest of the items are the remaining days

## Template

```
<template>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calendar-wrapper">
      <div class="calendar-row"
           v-for="(day, idx) in dayArr"
           :key="idx"
        >
          <div
            id="card"
            class="day-card unactive"
            @click="test(idx)"
          > 
              <div class="card-info">
                <p class="name">{{ dayOfWeek }}</p>
                <p class="day">
                    {{ currDay }} 
                </p>
              </div>
             <div class="dot-wrapper">
                <div class="dot-status undone" />
                <div class="dot-status undone" />
             </div>
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

## Script

```
 setup() {
        const moment = require('moment')
        const m = moment

        // Get the remaining month days starting from today:
        const daysRemainingThisMonth = moment().endOf('month').diff(moment(), 'days');

        // Turn the remaining days into an array for future rendering in the Template
        let dayArr = Array(daysRemainingThisMonth)
    
        // Get the index of a clicked calendar item:
        const test = (idx) => {
            console.log(idx + 1);
        }

        // Get the current day:
        const currDay = m().format('D')
        // Get the current week day:
        const dayOfWeek = m().format('dddd')
}
```

I believe that there is a way to somehow access each calendar element and give it it's own data, but I have no idea how

Comment: Might be off topic, but it's recommended to not use momentJs anymore in new projects, [more info here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/). You could try [Dayjs](https://day.js.org/) which all the api are basically same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed your code using `moment` features and it shows correctly in [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5u4wag?file=src/App.vue) link.

As you see I use `moment().add(<countingOfDiffrenceFromToday>, 'day')` to reach the exact day and push it to the array and use it in `v-for` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much! But why does it start from the 5th and not from the current day?

Comment: sorry for that.  You're right. I've changed it to `moment().add(<countingOfDiffrenceFromToday>, 'day')` so it works well now. Hope you find it useful. I will edit the main response to prevent making others do the wrong.

Comment: You're a life saver, I appreciate your help! Thank you for your time!

Comment: My pleasure. I'm happy to help.